# mongodb driver installation failed after homebrew mongodb installation osx

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I installed mongodb using homebrow on OSX Yosemite using 'brew install mongodb'  Then I went to install mongodb driver using 'npm install mongodb'.  This is what I got:

```
-
> kerberos@0.0.14 install /Users/adminname/WebstormProjects/Server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/kerberos.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/adminname/WebstormProjects/Server/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
mongodb@2.0.43 node_modules/mongodb
├── es6-promise@2.1.1
├── readable-stream@1.0.31 (string_decoder@0.10.31, isarray@0.0.1, core-util-is@1.0.1, inherits@2.0.1)
└── mongodb-core@1.2.12 (bson@0.4.12, kerberos@0.0.14)
Westons-MBP-2:Server adminname$
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved the issue for me.

cd /usr/local/lib sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.5.dylib

Then,
sudo npm install mongo

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2933

Answer (score 0):

Try to install mongodb with sudo user

> sudo npm install mongodb